# Removing Html tags from speciific place

Tags: html, tags

I am facing problem in removing html tags from specific place.  i have created a website based on php and html , its kind of blog and i am using ckeditor as text editor , so when i create a post , i have one  page as details.php and one home page in home page i show few content and in details page show full content of my post..

I want to remove all html tags of that post  from the imdex page but i want them to work in detail page , html tags like blockquote , h4 , color , etc... so can someone guide me how to remove html tags from a specific area.?

Comment: Do you have any code to explain the issue more thorough?

Comment: <h2><strong>Hello Everyone</strong></h2>
<p><strong>This is my first post</strong></p>. In this code i want that Html tags like p , strong and h2 tags should make effect in details. php page but in front page where i am showing limited info of it their it should not show any effect of html tags , like in blogger home pahe don't show any color or any formatted text but once enter in a post it has many fotmatted text.

Comment: It's pretty hard to clearly understand the end point what you what to achieve, but it sounds like you have to use javascript to manipulate DOM elements

Comment: my main aim is to remove the html tags From specific area.

Comment: ok i got it , what i wanted , u wanted to strip the html tags which can be done using strip_tags function of php.